# Viewing the compiled Sitecore config on Content Delivery?

Tags: configuration, site-configuration, content-delivery

On Content Authoring servers, you can go to the control panel and view this page to see the compiled Sitecore config: `/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx`. 
It's also possible to do this via Sitecore Rocks.

However I don't know a way of doing this on Content Delivery servers.

Can anyone suggest, how can we verify config settings on Content Delivery server?

Comment: As others have stated it's most likely not accessible due to Security Hardening in the Delivery environment. If you just want a sneak peak at it you can grab a copy of the ShowConfig.aspx file, drop it anywhere that isn't restricted, hit the URL quick then remove it again. I used this technique recently in 8.1 and it worked great.

Comment: I have the same issue, but when i try to open showconfig on CD node i have an error "Unothorized_client", so i tried to provide full permis-s to Anonymous logon\users to the folder "sitecore/admin" but with no success. I did patch of CD configurations and tried to see it on ShowConfigLayers.aspx on CM node also with no success, there are no my changes.
So is there a way to use showconfig on CD node or how can i check my pach is working according to the compiled config files ?
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Tim did to try the option below for config builder on CD instead?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's easier Today if you work with Sitecore 9, you can do it from your Content Management server. Just go to /sitecore/admin/ShowConfigLayers.aspx and select Content Delivery.

This is article explaining in details how to [View configuration changes](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/view-configuration-changes.html)

Comment: But this doesn't really show you the config of the CD server.  It analyzes the config on the CM server and shows you stuff for the Content Delivery role.  If you have differences in config settings between CM and CD it won't show you those.

Answer (score 5):

You can view configuration using below url for CD (Content Delivery from Content Management)

[https://cm-url/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx?role=ContentDelivery](https://cm-url/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx**?role=ContentDelivery**)

Comment: When I asked this question it was referring to 8.2 (although not specified). This option is available in 9.0 and above only but is a good alternative if your on 9 or above: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/view-configuration-changes.html

Comment: What if I have multiple CD? From which CD this will show?

Comment: I am not sure, how it can show details for multiple CD instance, but you can specify your environments as well like env=prod or env=stage. Note: It only shows you your configurations based on your pre-defined config values based on that instance only not actually fetches details from other instances. So if you make an change in CD specifically, and try to access details in CM, CM won't show you your cd changes as two webapps are not connected.

Comment: I don't believe it shows the config files from the actual CD servers. Instead, it looks at the config files on the CM server and lets you see the configuration of those that are set to role:require="ContentDelivery". It assumes your config files are the same on both CM and CD, and you're using role:require to indicate which settings apply to which servers.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to see it in the CD nodes as well. If you can't see is because most likely there is a permission restricting it as per the recommendations on the Sitecore scaling guide(making it to throw a 403 forbidden error). If that's your case you can change the permissions on IIS on the folder sitecore/admin and set it to *Anonymous*

Comment: If you do this, just remember to change it back.  Security, and all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer is available but in the Sitecore 9.0.2 azure I found a quick solution.

Comment out following two tags in the web.config

```
<location path="sitecore">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

and

```
<rule name="Sitecore Login or Admin Force HTTPS Redirection" enabled="true" 
      stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(sitecore/(login|admin))$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
          </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" 
               redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

But do remember to enable these tags again after you are done.